# Sorting Multiple Keys in VBA; Runtime Error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, runtime-error

I have been writing this VBA code to help me sort a database of information I have (Name, Invoice#, Address, etc). I recently learned how to sort in VBA without selecting the actual range in the worksheet and with that I tried sorting with multiple keys (key1, key2, key3), but no luck. I keep getting a Run time error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment when running this code. I want to be able to sort a range of data multiple times, so for instance sort a range (A:K) by column F, then by E, then by B etc.

Here is the code I have been using for sorting my columns:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:K").Sort _
Key1:=ActiveSheet.Range("F2"), Order1:=xlAscending, HEADER:=xlYes, Ordercustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
Key2:=ActiveSheet.Range("E2"), Order2:=xlAscending, HEADER:=xlYes, Ordercustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
Key3:=ActiveSheet.Range("D2"), Order3:=xlAscending, HEADER:=xlYes, Ordercustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal
```

It is weird, because at first I tried running the first 2 keys (key1, key2) and it worked perfectly fine, then I copied and pasted down to create the next key (key3) and the error came up. When I try to debug, all the code above gets highlighted.

The only other way I can think of is to run the code where the range (A:K) gets selected in the worksheet, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: You're specifying parameters for `HEADER`, `OrderCustom`, and `Orientation` multiple times.  I'd try removing the duplicate parameters first.  See the param list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx).

Comment: I'd start by recording a macro that does the sort you want. Copy and paste the code here to compare or maybe it'll be enough info so you can fix it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to rework some recorded macro code. The recorded code for a recorded [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) is very verbose. Here is all that you should require.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Intersect(.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, .Range("A:K"))
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(6), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Key2:=.Columns(5), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                    Key3:=.Columns(4), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End With
```

TBH, I do not know if you can simply add `Ordercustom:=1` to each line of that. IIRC, custom sorts cannot be performed on more than a single field at a time. In that case, perform three sorts, each with a `Ordercustom:=1` but remember to do it in reverse order; e.g. column D first, then E and finally the primary sort on column F.

Please note that there are a maximum of three columns to set the primary sort and secondary sorts to with this method. If you require more, sort on those first and run a subsequent sort on the last three prevalent columns.

Comment: If you are willing to supply the 'custom sort' then I could actually test this against sample data. Without the custom sort order specifics, any supplied response is a bit of a guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried your above code and it worked perfectly. It was definitely an issue with duplicating parameters.